# Parsing MagTek EMV TLV

Tags: c#, emv, tlv

I'm working with a MagTek DynaPro in a project to read credit card data and enter it into an accounting system (not my first post on this project). I've successfully leverage **Dukpt.NET** to decrypt MSR data, so that's been good (https://github.com/sgbj/Dukpt.NET). So I started working on getting the EMV data, and I've used the following MagTek document for TLV structure reference: https://www.magtek.com/content/documentationfiles/d99875585.pdf (starting at page 89). However, I'm having trouble reading the data.

I tried using **BerTlv.NET** (https://github.com/kspearrin/BerTlv.NET) to handle parsing the data, but it always throws an exception when I pass the TLV byte array to it. Specifically, this is what I get:

```
System.OverflowException : Array dimensions exceeded supported range.
```

I've also tried running the data through some other utilities to parse it out, but they all seem to throw errors, too. So, I think I'm left with trying to parse it on my own, but I'm not sure about the most efficient way to get it done. In some instances I know how many bytes to read in to get the data length, but in other cases I don't know what to expect.

Also, when breaking some of the data, I get to the *F9* tag, and between it and the *DFDF54* tag the hex reads as 8201B3. Now, the 01B3 makes sense considering  the leading two bytes for full message length are 01B7, but I don't understand the 82. I can't assume that's the tag for "EMV Application Interchange Profile" since that's listed under the *F2* tag.

Also, there's some padding of zeros (I think up to eight bytes worth) and four bytes of something else at the end that are excluded from two-byte message length at the very beginning. I'm not certain if that data being passed into parsers is causing a problem or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer the spec screenshot 1, as per EMV specs you are supposed to read the tags like below.

```
Eg tag 9F26 [1001 1111] the subsequent byte is also tag data - [0010 0110]
But when it is 9A [1001 1010], tag data is complete, length follows.
```

[image]

The spec also says to check the bit 8 of second byte of tag to see whether a third byte of tag follows like below, but practically you will not require it.

[image]

In real life you know upfront the tags you will encounter, so you parse through the data byte by byte, if you get 9F you look for the next byte to get the full tag and then next one byte of length, and if it is 9A, the next byte is length.

Note that length is also in Hex, which mean, 09 means 9 bytes, where as 10 means 16 bytes. For 10 bytes it is 0A.

I now bless you to fly!!

Comment: Ok, so I did just go through and pick the TLV data apart, piece by piece. It turns out that the responses are not standard to BER-TLV or even to the format laid out in MagTek's own documentation. I was able to find all the pieces after a lot of patience, and there are tags which do not appear to be defined with any EMV standards. Now I just have to figure out how to tell between chip and stripe reads, amongst other things. Thank you.

Comment: Michael how did you split the data apart? I have been trying to Decrypt DFDF59 but it does not output correctly using DUKTP

Comment: DUPKT has nothing to do with parsing. DUPKT is for encrypting data using a one time use key derived from BDK, and you will derive the same key at the other end, and decrypt the data using it. Once you have clear data, you can put the parsing rule as mentioned above. Just to make sure your DUPKT implementation is correct, i would suggest to test a wide variety of data and see whether you are able to decrypt at the other end without any issue. Debugging it in a production environment will become even hard.

Comment: DUKPT works with Magtek MSR, Currently attempting to decrypt Tag DFDF59(encrypted data), using DFDF56 (KSN), Track 2 equivalent data nor clear PAN appear to be present, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

While @adarsh-nanu's answer provides the exact BER-TLV specs I believe what @michael-mccauley was encountering was MagTek's invalid usage of TLV tags.  I actually stumbled through this exact scenario for the IDTech VIVOpay where they also used invalid tags.

I rolled my own TLV parsing routines and I specifically called out the non-conforming tags to force set a length when not in BER-TLV conformance.  See example code below:

```
int TlvTagLen(uchar *tag)
   {
   int len = 0;            // Tag length

   // Check for non-conforming IDTech tags 0xFFE0 : 0xFFFF
   if ((tag[0] == 0xFF) &&
       ((tag[1] >= 0xE0) && (tag[1] <= 0xFF)))
      {
      len = 2;
      }

   // Check if bits 0-4 in the first octet are all 1's
   else if ((tag[len++] & 0x1F) == 0x1F)
      {
      // Remaining octets use bit 7 to indicate the tag includes an
      // additional octet
      while ((tag[len++] & 0x80) == 0x80)
         {
         // Include the next byte in the tag
         }
      }

   return len;
   }
```